# Rails testing: assert render action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

How can I write a test to assert that the action `new` is rendered?

```
def method
  ...
  render :action => :new
end
```

I'm looking for something like the lines below, but to assert that the action was called, not the template:

```
assert_equal layout, @response.layout
assert_equal format, @request.format
```

I know I can't do `@response.action`

Thanks in advance!

Deb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer is wrong. As @Mohammad El-Abid indicated below, the correct method is:

```
assert_template :new
```

Original answer:

> The view would be *rendered*, the action *called*.
>  Try this:
>
>      `@controller.expects(:new)`

Comment: This tests that the action method got called. An action can render any view it chooses or even redirect.

Answer (score 89):

For future people that find this, the correct method is:

```
assert_template :new
```

Comment: documentation link: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TemplateAssertions/assert_template

Answer (score 9):

Let's say you have a controller action for create, as follows:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the standard Scaffold 'posts#new' view

```
<h1>New post</h1>

<% form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
...... # just to show, it's bigger....
```

Now, if a Post is succesfully created you want to be redirected, but if it fails, we just want to re-render the NEW action.  The test below uses what our main man DJTripleThreat said to use `assert_template`.

```
  test "should not create post and instead render new" do
    post :create, :post => { }

    assert_template :new
    #added to doubly verify
    assert_tag :tag => "h1", :child => /New post/
  end
```

If that still doesn't float your boat, I'd even add an assert_tag to make sure some of the view is coming up, so you know that it is displayed/rendered to the end user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

As of Rails 5.0.0, you can test that the action is rendered properly by testing the displayed template.

You first need to add the `rails-controller-testing` gem to your Gemfile (as it was extracted outside of Rails since version 5). Then, in your test, simply use:

`assert_template :new`